# Crossfilter aggregation against large volume of data

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I am working in Cross filter, 
We have customer order table, In this table we have information about order lines such as item Quantity, UOM (Each, Cases, Pallets etc…)

```
     CustomerOrderid    SKU     Each    Cases  OrderQuantity OrderDate 
     13516              129209  1.2     2      15            01/05/2015
     13516              129210  1       7.5    10            01/12/2015 
     13516              129211  1.3     1.2    2             01/20/2015
     13516              129212  1.2     2.3    4             01/28/2015
     13516              129213  1.6     1.6    6             02/09/2015
     13516              129214  2.4     2.4    8             02/17/2015
     13516              129215  2.1     2.8    11            02/18/2015
     13516              129216  2.2     2.9    7             03/23/2015
     13516              129217  2.3     2.4    1             03/24/2015
     13516              129218  2.4     2.4    4             03/25/2015
     13516              129219  1       1.9    6             03/30/2015
     13516              129220  1.1     2.7    4             04/06/2015
     13516              129221  1.5     2.8    1             04/13/2015
     13516              129222  1.6     2.4    6             04/22/2015
     13516              129223  1       1.5    1             04/28/2015
```

This table contains the historic data, it contains the past 5 years data. 
We need to display the chart for Average units of Each and Average units of cases based on Day of Week. If user selects the “Each”, then we need to display Average of Each, if user selects the “Cases”, then we need to display the Average of Cases.

We have done the above item using D3 Bar chart and Google big query. This is working fine.

Every time we just call the db and fetch the data based on user selection.

Expected Output

```
      DAYOFWEEK     AVG_Units(Cases)    AVG_Units(Each) 
      Monday        3.05714         1.37142
      Tuesday       1.875           1.75
      Wednesday     2.475           1.825
```

we have implemented the cross filter to display the chart details by Year. We just download the 105 million data text file and kept it in our local environment, where the d3 chart is running, and then we just loading the distinct OrderDate years in pie chart using cross filter library, if user clicks the year as 2015 in pie chart, then the report should displays Average of (Each\Cases) for which, OrderDate falling under 2010.

I have used the following code to achive this, if we have 10L records in the text file it is working fine, if we have 105Million record in the file then my browser is getting crashed. 
Please advise to resolve this.

```
     <script>      

         var j = jQuery.noConflict();
        j(document).ready(function () {

            d3.csv("SmallDB.txt", function (error, data) {
                var dayOfWeekChart = dc.barChart("#Canvas");
                var chart = dc.pieChart("#test");
                var numberFormat = d3.format('.2f');

                data.forEach(function (d) {
                    d.dd = new Date(d.OrderDate);
                    d.Year = d.dd.getFullYear();
                });



                //Pie chart Start

                    var index = -1;
                    var ndx = crossfilter(data),
                        runDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
                            var a = parseInt(d.Year);
                            return "Year-" + a;
                        });
                    speedSumGroup = runDimension.group().reduceSum(
                        function (d, i) {
                            var b = parseInt(d.Year);
                            return  b;
                        });

                    chart
                      .width(600)
                      .height(300)
                        .transitionDuration(1000)
                      .slicesCap(4)
                      .innerRadius(70)
                      .dimension(runDimension)
                      .group(speedSumGroup)
                      .legend(dc.legend());

                    chart.render();
                    chart.filter = function (d) {
                        OrderDateRange(d);
                    };

                //Pie chart End

                //Bar Chart Start
                    function OrderDateRange(data) {

                        var dayOfWeek = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
                            return d.dd.getDay();
                        });

                        var AVGUnitsDimGroup = fluctuation.group().reduce(
                        //add
                        function (p, v) {
                            ++p.count;
                            p.sum += v.Each / 1;
                            p.avg = p.sum / p.count;
                            return p;
                        },
                        //remove
                        function (p, v) {
                            --p.count;
                            p.sum += v.Each / 1;
                            p.avg = p.sum / p.count;
                            return p;
                        },
                        //init
                        function (p, v) {
                            return {
                                count: 0,
                                sum: 0,
                                avg: 0
                            };
                        });

                        dayOfWeekChart.width(400)
                        .height(300)
                        .margins({ top: 20, left: 50, right: 10, bottom: 20 })
                        .transitionDuration(1500)
                        .dimension(dayOfWeek)
                        .group(AVGUnitsDimGroup)
                        .valueAccessor(function (p) {
                            return p.value.avg;
                        })
                        .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]))
                        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)

                        .title(function (d) {
                            return d.value.avg;
                        })

                        .xAxisPadding(600)
                        .elasticX(true)
                        .elasticY(true)

                        dayOfWeekChart.render();

                    }

            })
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Likely a performance issue. "Millions" is probably pushing Crossfilter a bit too hard. I'd say use a smaller dataset to develop and optimize, then slowly scale up to your full dataset, profiling and optimizing along the way. One suggested performance improvement: Don't calculate the average in the Crossfilter group, but rather in the dc.js valueAccessor.

Comment: Hi Ethan Jewett, Thanks for your reply , How we can slowly scale up to our full dataset by loading smaller datasets, can u give any example of how to achieve this.

Comment: When you are developing, just use a portion of your dataset. So take SmallDB.txt and just use the first 5% of it, then use the first 20%, then 50%. When things start slowing down, jump into the Javascript profiler in your developer tools and see what the problem is.

Comment: That is likely to be too much data for crossfilter. To scale up, you could try sampling the data. If `d3.csv` is able to read the whole file, you could copy every other item to another array with `data2 = data.filter(function(d, i) { return i%2; })` and then chart that instead. If you're unable even to read the file, you could use unix `head` or `tail` to chop up the file before reading.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for your reply. my objective is to show average of each and cases in day of week as shown above ie., my aggregated row will be only 7 or less than 7. consider for example if i have split my data into first 5000 rows and generating my chart , again i will read first 10000 rows, this will update the existing chart. but when i scale up to full dataset , again i will get the same problem right?